# Python: List get the same items

Tags: python

i have a 3 lists.
I need the result to be the same items.

```
def main(args):
    list1 = ["hello", "day",   "apple", "hi",    "word"];
    list2 = ["food",  "hi",    "world", "hello", "python"];
    list3 = ["hi",    "hello", "april", "text",  "morning"];

    #result must be ["hi", "hello"]

    return 0;
```

How i can do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this yourself? What code did you use and what issues did you face?

Comment: i used `[i for i in list1 if i in list2]`, but this only two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try using python set intersection method**

```
list1 = ["hello", "day", "apple", "hi", "word"]
list2 = ["food", "hi", "world", "hello", "python"]
list3 = ["hi", "hello", "april", "text", "morning"]

set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
set3 = set(list3)

print(set1.intersection(set2).intersection(set3))
```

Output :

```
{'hello', 'hi'}
```

**Or You can also declare the list as set.**

```
set1 = {"hello", "day", "apple", "hi", "word"}
set2 = {"food", "hi", "world", "hello", "python"}
set3 = {"hi", "hello", "april", "text", "morning"}

print(set1.intersection(set2).intersection(set3))
```

*In this case all duplicates will be removed from the set1, set2 and set3*

Comment: Τhank you very much, it's what i need.

Comment: Or just `list(set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3))`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `set()`, you can just use list comprehensions:

```
list1 = ["hello", "day",   "apple", "hi",    "word"]
list2 = ["food",  "hi",    "world", "hello", "python"]
list3 = ["hi",    "hello", "april", "text",  "morning"]

print(list(i for i in (i for i in list1 if i in list2) if i in list3))
```

Prints:

```
['hello', 'hi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sets and the `&` operator to find the intersection:

`same_words = set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3)`

If you need to return a list back, just cast the set back to a list data type.

`return list(same_words)`